# Metal Framework not recognized

Tags: swift, macos, import, metal

I'm currently following this [tutorial on Metal/MetalKit](http://metalkit.org/2016/01/04/introducing-the-metal-framework.html). I have not developed for OSX before, so this is a bit new to me.
A pretty banal problem, that I'm having right from the start is, that Xcode (7.2) does not recognize, that `Metal` is imported. Or in a way it does, but doesn't allow me to use it's contents.

This is the content of my `ViewController.swift`:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() {
            label.stringValue = "Your GPU name is:\n\(device.name!)"
        } else {
            label.stringValue = "Your GPU does not support Metal!"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error though:

[image: Error]

---

When I try to `import Metal` explicitly, Xcode tells me that it's already implicitly imported with `Cocoa`.

---

My Deployment Target is `OSX 10.11`:

[image: Deployment Target]

---

Why is this not working?

Comment: Is your Base SDK set to OS X 10.11?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but my Deployment Target is OSX 10.11. (Update)

Comment: I thought you were trying to build to the Simulator, which is not a valid target. Xcode isn't helpful about getting you through that and we all probably get bamboozled by this happening when we attempt to build to the Simulator. However, it looks like you're not even using the Simulator, due to targeting OS X and not iOS.

Comment: Yes exactly. The tutorial states this explicitly.

Comment: Base SDK is one of the build settings. But if your deployment target is 10.11 and you're using Xcode 7.2 it should be fine.

Comment: Yeah. Base SDK is "Latest OS X (OS X 10.11)"

Comment: I was able to build your code with no problem using Xcode 7.2 on OS X 10.11. So I'm not sure what the issue is. Only thing I can suggest is restarting Xcode and making a new project from scratch. Paste your code into a new Swift source file and try building the project again.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for trying it. I'll check if it works in a new project.

Comment: Yup. That fixed it. Not sure what went wrong then.
If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I was about to also suggest cleaning your project or restarting Xcode. I'm glad it worked, and happy that you liked the tutorial. Stay tuned for more advanced topics in the coming weeks :-)

Comment: Oh. You did the tutorial. Awesome. It's a really nice approach to Metal. I will indeed stay tuned.